# THREE.js squeeze object from its center

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, geometry

Trying to squeeze deck of below 3D object

[image]

i used by `deckGeometry.translate(50,50,0)` and gets

[image]

but i want the deck should be under or surrounded by black line
[image]

Also tried `deckGeometry.scale.set(0.9,0.9,1)` but result is not as expected

Any think which missing ?

Comment: It's not scaling, it's re-building of a geometry or shifting of its vertices. Take a look at this forum topic for some ideas: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/offsetcontour-function/3185?u=prisoner849

Comment: Thanks reviewing seems Exactly what i wanted!

Comment: @prisoner849 Great That Worked for me! I was struggling a lot with this
Thanks

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @prisoner849 in some cases i am having an infinite or a long shift value

Comment: In what cases? Any example?

Comment: have a look the infinite deck because of infinite shift
Vectors are mentioned in image
https://www.screencast.com/t/Yj6kcXGpZs1

Comment: if there are two collinear opposite vectors, then there is no surprise with such behaviour